# pandasで条件を満たした列に、条件を満たした行の値を代入する

Tags: python, pandas

house pricesのcsvで、lotfrontageが欠損しており、Lotshapeがregの時にLotAreaの平方根値を代入したく以下のコードを入れたのですが、動きませんでした。

```
all_data.loc[(all_data['LotFrontage'].isnull()) & (all_data['LotShape'] == 'Reg'),'LotFrontage'] = np.sqrt(all_data['LotArea'])
```

エラーコードは以下です。

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')` として、同じ処理を行ってみましたがエラーは発生しませんでした。`test.csv` でも同様です。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
やはりtrainとtestデータを結合したのが原因そうですね

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**インデックスが重複している**のでしょう。よくあるエラーです。
以下の内、どれかが動くと思うので試してみてください。

```
all_data.loc[(all_data['LotFrontage'].isnull()) & (all_data['LotShape'] == 'Reg'),'LotFrontage'] = np.sqrt(all_data['LotArea'].values())

all_data.loc[(all_data['LotFrontage'].isnull()) & (all_data['LotShape'] == 'Reg'),'LotFrontage'] = np.sqrt(all_data['LotArea'].values)

all_data.loc[(all_data['LotFrontage'].isnull()) & (all_data['LotShape'] == 'Reg'),'LotFrontage'] = np.sqrt(all_data['LotArea'].values())

all_data.loc[(all_data['LotFrontage'].isnull()) & (all_data['LotShape'] == 'Reg'),'LotFrontage'] = np.sqrt(all_data['LotArea']).values()

all_data.loc[(all_data['LotFrontage'].isnull()) & (all_data['LotShape'] == 'Reg'),'LotFrontage'] = np.sqrt(all_data['LotArea'].values())

all_data.loc[(all_data['LotFrontage'].isnull()) & (all_data['LotShape'] == 'Reg'),'LotFrontage'] = np.sqrt(all_data['LotArea']).values
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
インデックスの重複のせいなのですね・・・
おそらくtrainデータとtestデータをconcatで結合したあとに、今回の処理をしたせいですね
ご指摘頂いた`.value`の方法ためしたのですが、以下のエラーが出てできませんでした。
`TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`

Comment: ですが、
今回の処理の前にreset.indexを実行するとうまくいきました。

```all_data = all_data.reset_index(drop=True)```
```all_data.loc[(all_data['LotFrontage'].isnull()) & (all_data['LotShape'] == 'Reg'),'LotFrontage'] = np.sqrt(all_data['LotArea'])```